# Struts 2 jQuery Subscribe is called more than once

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

In the struts 2 jQuery plugin there is a publish/subscribe framework which can be used for event invocation.

Consider this sample....

One can change the grid behavior when grid is loaded by subscribing too `onGridCompleteTopics` event

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable" dataType="json"
    href="%{url}" gridModel="gridModel" direction="%{pageDir}" width="800"
    shrinkToFit="true" onGridCompleteTopics="grid_compelete">
```

And then in the js:

```
    $.subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {
    //do some thing
}
```

The problem is that, as above js and the grid are in the same page (they are in one jsp), every time I reload the page the `subscribe` is called and the code in the subscribe runs  again.

How can I prevent it?! I found a function in  `jquery.subscribe.1.2.3` which is called `isSubscribed` I thought the framework should use it internally to avoid this issue. But it is not!

Also I did not find any way to call and use this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution was found at [Struts 2 jQuery plugin isSubscribe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708551/struts-2-jquery-plugin-issubscribe-not-working)

One can use

```
  $("#gridtable").subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {
    //do some thing
}
```

or kill the topic (which I do not prefer it myself)

```
 $.subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {
    //do some thing
    $.destroyTopic('grid_compelete');
}
```

The isSubscibe is still there and it is attached to document, please see [Struts 2 jQuery plugin isSubscribe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708551/struts-2-jquery-plugin-issubscribe-not-working) for complete code by @Roman C

Answer (score 2):

> every time I reload the page the subscribe is called and the code in
>   the subscribe runs again.

Of course, that's the standard behavior. If you need something to be ran only once, in the entire life-cycle, you can use session/cookies.

`onGridCompleteTopics` - This means everytime the grid loads the topic is published. And everytime the page is reloaded/refreshed the grid is loaded, publishing the event.

Hope so it clears your doubt.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find if the subscription to this topic is already done!

Comment: as I suggested, you can use cookies. Get a variable from cookie, if not found, run your code & save the var in cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for **onEditInlineSuccessTopics** and replacing

```
$.subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {
```

with

```
$("#gridtable").subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {
//do some thing
}
```

was the best solution that worked for me.

The other version related to destroyTopic, made the topic work only the first time I edited a row and if I wanted to edit another row, the topic was not called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use return false; at the end of function.

```
$.subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {
    return false;
});
```